# Styling input file in contact form 7

Tags: css, wordpress, contact-form

I'm trying to replace that old input file with something modern that i designed in the fiddle. However since i'm using WP contact form 7 is integrated into theme and the only way i can edit it is via this code -

```html
<label>  
    [text* your-name placeholder "Your Name (required)"] </label>

<label>  
    [email* your-email placeholder "Your email (required)"] </label>

<label> 
    [text your-subject placeholder "Subject"] </label>

<label> 
    [textarea your-message placeholder "Your Message"] </label>
[file file-442 limit:10485760 filetypes:doc|pdf|csv class:cv]

[submit "AHOI!"]
```

So is there a way to replace this last input where the file is with my input and hide original input? This is my input

```css
input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}

.custom-file-upload {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  color: #083a50;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 0.5em 2em 0.25em 1em;
  user-select: none;
}

.upload {
  height: 1.75em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.25em;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <img class="upload"src="http://www.plaforma.me/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/SEND-FILE-IKONICA.png" width="300" height="53" alt=""> Select File
</label>
<input id="file-upload" type="file" />
```

Don't know why here doesn't load icon next to text but there is icon, so anyone got idea how could i replace original in contact form 7?

Comment: Its working good in https://codepen.io/navdeepsingh/pen/bmejjq

Comment: It is, but how can i replace original in the contact form? I tried with display:none but when i send it with my input, file is not sent

Comment: you can define label and and image into cf7 and can assign class to the file input to grab you css instead of its default

Comment: Sounds good, will try now that

Comment: I have tried assigning class of a label to a file but then he grabs everything and remove logic of opening file

Comment: @Blazo, did you get this to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For styling, file input type the http://markusslima.github.io/jquery-filestyle library is very good.

```
$(":file").jfilestyle({input: false, text: "Select File"});
```

Also, see the options here. http://markusslima.github.io/jquery-filestyle/options.html

Comment: Your options will be like this: $(":file").jfilestyle({input: false, text: "Select File"});
for styling options follow this: http://markusslima.github.io/jquery-filestyle/extends.html